# Ackermann real numbers python

Tags: python-3.x, recursion, ackermann

How can one compute the Ackermann function over nonnegative real numbers in Python per [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/146786/ackermanns-function-over-the-reals) on Mathoverflow?

Here is my code for integers.

```
def naive_ackermann(m, n):
    global calls
    calls += 1
    if m == 0:
        return n + 1
    elif n == 0:
        return naive_ackermann(m - 1, 1)
    else:
        return naive_ackermann(m - 1, naive_ackermann(m, n - 1))
```

I tried using float and allowing it to go in between 0 and 1 but it was not continuous.

Comment: Have you tried computing the Ackermann function over nonnegative integers?

Comment: Yes. I have. It worked.

Comment: Gave a different one a shot in bc. Not contiguous but here it is: define ack(m, n) { if ( m < 1 && m >= 0 ) return (m+n+1); if ( n < 1 ) return (ack(m-1, 1)); return (ack(m-1, ack(m, n-1)));}